# Monotouch 6.0 >> Monodevelop 3.0.4.7 hangs during build

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

After updating Monotouch on 6.0, MonoDevelop on 3.0.4.7 all projects hang during build (on first project)

I've created new empty Monotouch project for iPhone result is the same - MonoDevelop hangs on start building

On previous Monotouch 5.4.0 and Monodevelop 3.0.3 all worked

OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_6/MonoTouch_6.0) MonoTouch 6.0 does not support Snow Leopard (OSX 10.6).

You'll need to update to OSX Lion (10.7) or Mountain Lion (10.8) or use an earlier version of MonoTouch (5.4 still supports Snow Leopard).

Note that iOS6 support requires Apple Xcode 4.5 which does not work on Snow Leopard either.